# Play Framework 2.X variable route broken when using IIS frontend

Tags: iis, playframework-2.0, production, dev-to-production

I have a play framework route that fetches dynamic files from a storage folder looking like:

`GET    /routeName/:path   controllers.SomeController.someFunction(path: String)`

Where a valid relative address is given for path.

When I run on localhost, in dev or production mode, everything works fine. When I use IIS to rewrite another URL to that localhost, though all other parts of the site work, the route breaks and I get

`Not Found
For request 'GET /routeName/thePathIGave'`

Why does the route break, and what can I do to resolve the issue or work around it?

Answer (score 0):

I never learned what caused the problem, but I eventually worked around the problem by changing

```
GET    /routeName/:path
```

to

```
GET    /routeName/*path
```